# how to disable layout alignments?

Tags: java, android, graphics

Im trying to align a bunch of objects in eclipse with the android plugin. They all link to each other, which is problematic when I change the text inside the boxes. What can I do to change how it automatically aligns? Set all the android: layout ...="" to "false"? here is the xml file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/chckBxContd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@+string/RunContd"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblUke"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/chckBxContd"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:text="@+string/lblUke"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCUke"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lblUke"
    android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lblUke"
    android:text="@+string/btnCUke" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnGUke"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnCUke"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnCUke"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/lblUke"
    android:text="@+string/btnGUke" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnEUke"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnGUke"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnGUke"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:text="@+string/btnEUke" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAUke"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnEUke"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnEUke"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnCUke"
    android:text="@+string/btnAUke" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblGuitar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@+string/lblGuitar"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnDGuitar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnAUke"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lblGuitar"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:text="@+string/btnDGuitar" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAGuitar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnDGuitar"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnDGuitar"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnGUke"
    android:text="@+string/btnAGuitar" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnLowEGuitar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnAGuitar"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnAGuitar"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnEUke"
    android:text="@+string/btnLowEGuitar" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnGGuitar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnLowEGuitar"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnLowEGuitar"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="@+string/btnGGuitar" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnBGuitar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnGGuitar"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnGGuitar"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@+string/btnBGuitar" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnHighEGuitar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnBGuitar"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnDGuitar"
    android:text="@+string/btnHighEGuitar" />
```

This is what I'd Like it to look like, the text being objects...
[image]

and here is the picture of what the program is looking like, it also has some buttons that say false, when they should say a letter, not sure what that's about..[image]

Comment: how should they align to each other in the end? if your `TextView` is getting to wide you could use `maxWidth`

Comment: my issue is that everything is getting spread, including buttons, not just textViews. If I could somehow remove relationships and just place the objects where I want them, the problem would be solved.

Comment: maybe you should post a graphic which shows how it should look like. if you want all the items next to each other, use a `LinearLayout` with `orientation=horizontal`. If you want every item to take the same width, take a look at `GridView` (sorry, still not sure what you trying to achieve)

Comment: once the emulator comes up,i'll post what it looks like. for now, check at the edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is the layouts are resizing widths when the text changes.

A possible solution would be to use a `TableLayout` in conjunction with `TableRows` instead.  TableLayouts will align everything together in the same with. When the text inside changes, the row sizes will remain static.

Or you can use `LinearLayout` with each row.  Set the `weightSum` attribute to some arbitrary number.  Set each `TextView` (or whatever direct child is in the `LinearLayout`) `weight` attribute to half of the weightSum.  The `LinearLayout` will keep the containers the same size regardless of what the text is.

In fact, TableLayout extends LinearLayout and this is the underlying mechanics behind it.

Comment: This fixed most of the issues! Thanks, I went with the TableLayout and Table Rows. This is my first android program if it isn't obvious, I appreciate the help, I'll get the hang of it eventually!